# 2n points on a circle in two different colors. Prove that pairwise distances of same-color points are the same

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, graph-theory

There are $2n$ points on a circle. The distance (defined by shortest distance you would take to walk from one point to another along the circle) between adjacent points are the same. $n$ points are black and $n$ points are white.

Now we compute the pairwise distances between all the black points and pairwise distances between all the white points. Prove they have the same collection ( with multiplicities) of pairwise distances.

It looks like there has to be a simple trick to map from one group of points to the other through some reflection principle. But I haven't figured out a way...

Comment: I am facing a similar problem. Do you know where this problem come from ? Or where can I get similar variations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Fill in any gaps yourself.)

**Step 1:** Consider any ring comprising of B's and W's (with possibly an unequal number of them).

> Show that the number of $BW$ (in that order) is equal to the number of $WB$.

> Show that the number of $BB$ is equal to the number of $B$ minus the number of $BW$.

**Step 2:** Given the setup, fix $d$. Then, construct a ring of $B$ and $W$ by taking point 1, going around distance $d$ till we loop back.
If there are leftover points (when $\gcd(d,2n)\ne 1$), then take another starting point to form multiple loops.

**Step 3:** For the (possibly multiple) loops corresponding to $d$, each individual loop has the same number of BW and WB. The total across all these loops have $n$ $B$'s and $n$ $W$'s.

> Show that the total number of $BB$ and $WW$ are equal.

Hence conclude that in the setup, the number of distances of length $d$ are equal.

Hence, the multi-set of distances are equal.

Comment: I am facing a similar problem. Do you know where this problem come from ? Or where can I get similar variations?

Answer (score 3):

consider the set of all pairwise distance of black, if distance $j$ is not in it, then $x \mapsto x+j$ is a bijection between black and white.

If we take multiplicity into consideration, the multiplicity of black $j$ is number of points that itself is black and maps to black, it is the same as # of points that is white and maps to white.

Comment: How exactly do you see that?

Comment: @R.Yeh Since the points are equally spaced around the circle, for any fixed $k$ the map $x \mapsto x+k$ [mod $2n$] is a bijection. And if no pairwise distance is $k$ then any black maps to a white (and conversely).

Comment: Okay, but what if ... all the pairwise distances are present between black points? E.g. regular octagon $A_1A_2\cdots A_8$ where points $A_1,A_2,A_3$ and $A_6$ are black and the rest are white?

Comment: @StinkingBishop: In that case consider the pairwise distances of white: either they include all possible distances, or you can use a missing one to get a bijection between white and black.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Ah, I must've misunderstood the problem. I thought the claim was that the set of all distances *with multiplicities* matched. (In my octagon example, every distance occurs *and* the multiplicities match.) I wonder if this stronger statement is true...

Comment: @StinkingBishop that is my intention though.. with multiplicities. let me edit my original post..

Comment: Then I feel this answer is insufficient, or at least incomplete. I believe it can be clarified, e.g. if we fix $j$ and put $f_j(x)=x+j$, and if $A$ is a point, then look at $(A, f_j(A)), (f_j(A),f^2_j(A)),\ldots$ Prove that this eventually cycles back, i.e. $f^i_j(A)=A$ for some $i$. Now, if the diagonal $(A,f_j(A))$ was "black/white", eventually one of the diagonals $(f^i_j(A), f^{i+1}_j(A))$ is "white/black" as we must eventually hit "black" corner again - so we can associate $(A,f_j(A))$ with the *first* such diagonal...

Comment: [Cont'd.]  This proves that the number of "black/white" diagonals is the same as the number of "white/black" diagonals of "length" $j$ - which then implies that the number of "black/black" is the same as the number of "white/white" diagonals... Or, at least it seems to me that something like that needs to be added to complete the argument. (Sorry if I don't see it being obvious.)

Comment: @StinkingBishop You're very close to it.

Comment: @yisishoujo After writing up my solution, I realized it is the same as yours, just that you didn't have much details so it was hard (for Stinking Bishop) to see why.